# UWP - scaled image is damaged

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I have a problem to place an image with down-scale. Image is rasterized and I don't know find way to place it correctly.

Is it possible to place picture without losing quality ?

[image: Damaged imaged after down-scale]

Code:

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> BitmapTransform(string filePath, uint width)
        {

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
            if (file == null)
                return null;

            // create a stream from the file and decode the image
            var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);


            // create a new stream and encoder for the new image
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(ras, decoder);


            double ration = 
            enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = width;
            enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = (uint)(((double)decoder.PixelHeight / (double)decoder.PixelWidth) * (double)width);


            // write out to the stream
            try
            {
                await enc.FlushAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.ToString();
            }

            // render the stream to the screen
            BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
            bImg.SetSource(ras);
            return bImg;

        }
```

Comment: You cannot scale an image and not scale an image at the same time. Scaling an image will **always** affect image quality, and the only way to not affect image quality is to not scale an image. This should be immediately obvious.

Comment: but it's not upscale to more than 100%, it's resizing to about 50% depending of screen resolution.

Comment: Scaling an image down implies losing information. This leads to image quality degradation. If this weren't the case, we'd all just compress all our files to occupy 0 bytes of disk space, while retaining all information. I don't know why this isn't obvious to you.

Comment: I understand that, but this quality loss is so BIG. Normally when I scale a picture or photo in some application, this picture looks similiar. This is really huge quality losing, like some deformation.

Comment: You aren't dealing with a photograph, that has smooth transitions of colors between pixels. You are dealing with sharp edges. Scaling sharp edges will produce more visible image quality degradation. All the more since you are using point sampling (vs. bilinear or bicubic filtering).

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the way of resizing - Nearest Neighbor, Linear, Cubic, Fant - by BitmapTransform.InterporationMode property.
Have you tried it?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.interpolationmode

```
        double ration = 
        enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = width;
        enc.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = (uint)(((double)decoder.PixelHeight / (double)decoder.PixelWidth) * (double)width);
        enc.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic;  // <----- Set the Interporation mode here
```

But the quality of result is vary. It's depend on the original image.

Comment: This didn't work correctly. Width of picture is over 4000px and I need scale down picture to 1366px and so on ... Just prepare for every screen resolution.